# RSS Feed Reader for Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.5, wordpress, rss, rss-feed

I want to show the last articles from my blog (wordpress) in my store (magento 2.3.5). I`m looking for a RSS Feed reader, but after googling I only find solutions for Magento 1. Anyone knows any solution form Magento 2?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a extension that works reasonably well. This one:

https://marketplace.magento.com/decryptweb-reader.html

It lists the last articles of a rss feed. Although it needs some work in design, it works fine.